# Xamarin Forms: How to fetch the latest contacts of phone after adding a number to phonebook?

Tags: xamarin.forms, contacts, phonebook

I have referred to [this](https://www.xamboy.com/2019/10/10/getting-phone-contacts-in-xamarin-forms/) blog for listing the phone contacts. Also, I have implemented adding contacts to the phonebook using **DependencyService** as per [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/140702/how-to-add-new-contact-in-phone-book-contact-list-using-xamarin-forms) thread.

My problem is after adding a contact to the device phone book I need to fetch the entire latest contacts. Also, I need to show the new contact on the contact listview.

For reference, I have created a sample project and uploaded it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N-WuhXcHszGS52zpurn4gpbaTO4j1_35/view?usp=sharing). In this sample first of all I am **listing the phone contacts** with the **Add New** option on the top. If we tap **Add New**, a new page will open with the **Add to Contact** option and entry for phone number. Click the **Add to Contact** option after entering a phone number, then the device phonebook page will show with the phone number entered.

At this stage, the user may or may not save that number to the device phonebook. So when the user resuming to the App I need to fetch the entire contacts and check the phone number is added or not to the device phone book. If contact added I will hide the **Add to Contact** option else I will show that option again. At the same time when the user going back to the contact list, **I need to show the newly added contact over there.**

For this, I have added a message on **App.xaml.cs** and Subscribe it on **AddContactPage**.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    // Handle when your app resumes
    MessagingCenter.Send(this, "isContactAdded");
}
```

**AddContactPage**

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App>(this, "isContactAdded", (sender) =>
{
    //How I can fetch the entire latest contacts here
    //After fetching conatcts only I can check the new phone number is added to the device phonebook
});
```

The contacts are passing as an argument from **MainActivity** to **App.xaml.cs**. So I don't know how to fetch it directly. Is there any way to fetch all contacts on this page?

Comment: why wouldn't you just call `RetrieveContactsAsync`?

Comment: @Jason Using the `IContactsService` object we are calling `RetrieveContactsAsync`. But we have the old 'IContactsService' before adding a new contact. How we can fetch the latest `IContactsService` object?

Comment: it's a service, it doesn't have any state.  Whenever you call `RetrieveContactsAsync` it will get the most current data.

Comment: @Jason Let me try with that

Comment: Is something to update?

Comment: @AdrainZhu Almost completed

Comment: @Jason I have almost completed but still have one issue. If I add multiple contacts to the phone book then that MessagingCenter.Subscribe part is invoking multiple times. I try to add MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe on OnDisappearing but no luck. Any solution?

Comment: @Jason protected override void OnDisappearing()
 {
     base.OnDisappearing();
     MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<CallHistoryDetailPage, List<Contact>>(this, "isContactAdded");
 }

Comment: @AdrainZhu  I have almost completed but still have one issue. Please check the above the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//loading all the new contacts
protected async override void OnResume()
{
    if (Utility.isContactAdding)
    {
        UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("");
        List<Contact> contacts = await contactsService.RetrieveContactsAsync() as List<Contact>;
        MessagingCenter.Send<App, List<Contact>>(App.Current as App, "isContactAdded", contacts);
    }
}

//Comparing the new contacts with phone number
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, List<Contact>>(App.Current, "isContactAdded", (snd, arg) =>
{
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        Utility.ContactsList.Clear();
        phone = Regex.Replace(phone, @"[^0-9+]+", "");
        bool isContactExist = false;
        var AllNewContacts = arg as List<Contact>;
        foreach(var item in AllNewContacts)
        {
            if (item.PhoneNumbers.Length != 0)
            {
                foreach(var number in item.PhoneNumbers)
                {
                    if (number.Replace("-", "").Replace(" ","") == phone)
                    {
                        isContactExist = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            Utility.ContactsList.Add(item);
        }
        if (isContactExist)
        {
            Phonebook_layout.IsVisible = false;
            MessagingCenter.Send<CallHistoryDetailPage>(this, "refreshcontacts");
        }
        else
        {
            Phonebook_layout.IsVisible = true;
        }
        Utility.isContactAdding = false;
        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
    });
});

//Subscribed message and refershing the contacts
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CallHistoryDetailPage>(this, "refreshcontacts", (sender) =>
{
    BindingContext = new ContactsViewModel(Utility.myContacts);
});
```